# Obter tipo do BLOB PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Seguinte, preciso saber o tipo do BLOB que estou obtendo através do meu select, para que assim possa configurar um header("Content-Type") adequado, ou seja, se meu arquivo for PDF, definir header content como pdf, e assim por diante.... Não achei alguma solução parecida, mas segue minha duvida:

```
$sql = "select notaf_manutencao from manutencao_caminhao where id_manutencao = '$id'";
$exe = $conn->query($sql)
$pdf = mysqli_fetch_object($exe);; //Quero obter apenas o tipo de arquivo que veio.
```

Não queria utilizar alguma flag no meu banco pra saber o tipo, tem como obter diretamente pelo mysqli_fetch_object?
Obrigado.

Comment: Talvez algo tipo isso? https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mime-content-type.php

Comment: Mas ainda acho que o mais recomendado é ter o tipo do arquivo salvo em uma coluna no banco de dados

Comment: Isso mesmo, perfeito!